# The (modular) permutation representation of the affine group

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory

For a prime $p$, let $A_p$ denote the affine group over $\mathbb{F}_p$, consisting of all permutations of the form $\pi: x \mapsto ax+b$ for $a \in \mathbb{F}_p^*, b \in \mathbb{F}_p$. The set of all functions $S = \{ f: \mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2\}$ is a (permutation) representation of $A_p$ with the rule $[\pi f](x) = f(\pi^{-1} (x))$.

I see that $S = C \oplus K_\epsilon$, where $C$ is the (invariant) subspace of constant functions and $K_\epsilon$ is the (invariant) subspace of functions $f$ for which $\sum_x f(x) = 0$. Is $K_\epsilon$ irreducible? (If so, how do I see that?)

---

**Remarks**.

1. Note that $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{F}_2)$ does divide $|A_p|$ so that $\mathbb{F}_2[A_p]$ is not semisimple. (This places the problem outside my comfort zone...)
2. If the question above follows in a principled way from modular representation theory, a brief indication of what's necessary for the proof would be really valuable for me.
3. According to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200053/invariant-subspaces-of-an-f-2-representation-of-the-affine-linear-group-of-dim?rq=1, there are no other invariant subspaces, but this cites a paper in German which I cannot read.

Comment: Just a note: You should have an inverse in the definition of the representation, to make things work out.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thanks for noticing; I fixed it.

Comment: $K_\epsilon$ is indeed irreducible. One way to show this is to explicitly prove that the cyclic submodule $\mathbb{F}_2[A_p] \cdot f$ (for any non-zero $f$) contains the spanning set of vectors $\vec{j} - \vec{e}_i$ where $\vec{j}$ is the all-ones vector and $\vec{e}_i$ is the standard basis vector. For this purpose, assume w.l.o.g. that $f$ is non-zero in the first coordinate and add up the vectors in the orbit of $f$ under the stabilizer subgroup $H$ of the first coordinate: these sum to $\vec{j} - \vec{e}_1$ and the other vectors arise by applying appropriate elements of $A_p$.